# How to parse an heterogeneous tree in clojure

Tags: clojure, tree

I'm working on some Clojure code, in which I have a tree of entities represented as a nested vector like this:

```
(def tree '[SYMB1 "a" [SYMB2 {:k1 [SYMB1 "b" "c"]} "x"] {:k2 ["b" "c"]})
```

here, leaves are strings and nodes can be either symbols or maps. Each map having a key associated to a subtree or to a collection of leaves.

How can I render the tree above to get:

```
[SYMB1 "a" [SYMB2 [SYMB1 "b" "c"] "x"] "b" "c"]
```

Comment: What about `[SYMB {:k1 ["a" "b"]} {:k2 ["c" "d"]}]`, does that become `[SYMB "a" "b" "c" "d"]` so the collections in the map are flattened?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to throw away `:k1` and `:k2` whenever you encounter a map (and assume each map has only 1 key).  You can do this easily using `postwalk`:

```
(ns ...
  (:require
    [clojure.walk :as walk]
  ))

(def tree
  '[SYMB1 "a" [SYMB2 {k1 [SYMB1 "b" "c"]} "x"] {k2 ["b" "c"]} ])

(def desired
  '[SYMB1 "a" [SYMB2 [SYMB1 "b" "c"] "x"] ["b" "c"]])


  (let [result  (walk/postwalk
                  (fn [item]
                    (cond
                      (map? item) (do
                                    (when-not (= 1 (count item))
                                      (throw (ex-info "Must be only 1 item" {:item item})))
                                    (val (first item)))
                      :else item ))
                  tree) ]
    (is= desired result))

result => [SYMB1 "a" [SYMB2 [SYMB1 "b" "c"] "x"] ["b" "c"]]
```

Note that the results for `:k2` are still wrapped in a vector, unlike your original question. I'm not sure if that is what you meant or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using clojure.spec:

```
(ns tree
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]))

(def tree '[SYMB1 "a" [SYMB2 {:k1 [SYMB1 "b" "c"]} "x"] {:k2 ["b" "c"]}])

(s/def ::leaf string?)
(s/def ::leafs (s/coll-of ::leaf))

(s/def ::map
  (s/and
   map?
   (s/conformer
    (fn [m]
      (let [[_ v] (first m)]
        (s/conform (s/or
                    :node  ::node
                    :leafs ::leafs) v))))))

(s/def ::node (s/and
               (s/or :symbol ::symbol
                     :leaf ::leaf
                     :map ::map)
               (s/conformer second)))

(s/def ::symbol
  (s/and
   (s/cat :name
          symbol?
          :children
          (s/* ::node))
   (s/conformer (fn [parsed]
                  (let [{:keys [name children]} parsed]
                    (reduce
                     (fn [acc v]
                       (case (first v)
                         :leafs (into acc (second v))
                         :node  (conj acc (second v))
                         (conj acc v)))
                     [name]
                     children))))))

(s/conform ::node tree) ;; [SYMB1 "a" [SYMB2 [SYMB1 "b" "c"] "x"] "b" "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using postwak and some helper functions:

```
(defn clause-coll? [item]
  (and (vector? item)
       (symbol? (first item))))

(defn render-map[amap]
  (let [[[_ v]] (vec amap)]
    (if (clause-coll? v)
      [v]
       v)))

(defn render-item[item]
  (if (map? item) 
   (render-map item)
   [item]))

(defn render-level [[op & etc]]
  (->> (mapcat render-item etc)
       (cons op)))

(defn parse-tree[form]
  (clojure.walk/postwalk #(if (clause-coll? %)
                              (render-level %)
                              %)
                         form))
```

Answer (score 0):

Michiel's clojure.spec solution was clever and Alan's clojure.walk solution was concise.

Without using any libraries and walking the tree directly:

```
(def tree
     '[SYMB1 "a"
             [SYMB2 {:k1 [SYMB1 "b" "c"]}
                    "x"]
                    {:k2 ["b" "c"]}])

(defn get-new-keys
  "Determines next keys vector for tree navigation, can backtrack."
  [source-tree current-keys current-node]
  (if (and (vector? current-node) (symbol? (first current-node)))
      (conj current-keys 0)
      (let [last-index (->> current-keys count dec)]
        (let [forward-keys (update-in current-keys [last-index] inc)
              forward-node (get-in source-tree forward-keys)]
              (if forward-node
                  forward-keys
                  (if (= 1 (count current-keys))
                      current-keys
                      (recur source-tree (subvec current-keys 0 last-index) current-node)))))))

(defn convert-tree
      "Converts nested vector source tree to target tree."
      ([source-tree] (convert-tree source-tree [0] []))
      ([source-tree keys target-tree]
        (let [init-node       (get-in source-tree keys)
              node            (if (map? init-node)
                                  (first (vals init-node))
                                  (if (vector? init-node)
                                      []
                                      init-node))
              new-target-tree (update-in target-tree keys (constantly node))
              new-keys        (get-new-keys source-tree keys init-node)]
      (if (= new-keys keys)
          new-target-tree
          (recur source-tree new-keys new-target-tree)))))

user=> (convert-tree tree)
[SYMB1 "a" [SYMB2 [SYMB1 "b" "c"] "x"] ["b" "c"]]
```